# How to find nearest neighbors in sql teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, knn

I want to find 1 nearest neighbor for each customer from table `TG`. Decision must be done by using distance calculated on `val`.

One possible solution is to cross join table on himself, but 'TG' is size of 100k and the initial table 50 mln - to big output. So I came up with the idea using window function:

I'm failing to get such  algorithm to work. So how can I do that?

```
SELECT 
   cust_id2,
   MIN(CASE WHEN cust_id <> cust_id2 then cust_id end) -- to get for cust_id2 from TG another cust_id from all_custs table
   OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id2 
   ORDER BY SQRT(POWER(cur.val1 - pref.val1, 2) + POWER(cur.val2 - pref.val2, 2)) -- here I want to order by distance but I need current value and previous one. Nested windows function isn't allowed(
FROM 
(
   select all_custs.cust_id, val1, val2,  aa.cust_id2 from all_custs
   left join (sel cust_id as cust_id2 from TG) TG,  aa on aa.cust_id2 = all_custs.cust_id 
) AS dt
where cust_id2 is not null


`TG` - stores just ids - as numbers. Every cust from TG are also in `all_custs` 

Table all_custs 

cust_id (number) | val1(decimal) | val2(decimal)
_________________|_______________|_____________
123123131        | 123.1         | 2
234234241        | 75.15         | 5 
525165354        | 676.12        | 3
```

For the cust_id = 123123131   the closest one will be cust 234234241. There is might be more than one val column

UPD1: For the reference. This is how it can be done with cross join but shouldn't:

```
sel tg.cust_id as tg_cust_id, cg.cust_id as cg_cust_id
SQRT   (
            POWER((tg.val1 - cg.val1)/max_val1, 2) -- min = 0
          + POWER((tg.val2 - cg.val2)/max_val2, 2) -- min = 0 
       ) AS DIST
   from (
       sel arpau.cust_id, val1, val2
       from all_custs join TG aa on aa.cust_id2 = arpau.cust_id
       where arpau.branch_id = 95 
   ) tg
   join ( 
    sel arpau.cust_id, val1, Max(val1)  over(ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) max_val1
                     , val2, Max(val1)  over(ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) max_val2
            from all_custs left join TG aa on aa.cust_id2 = arpau.cust_id
       where aa.cust_id2 is null       
    ) cg  on  tg.cust_id <> cg.cust_id
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tg.cust_id ORDER BY DIST) = 1
```

Comment: Not knowing what `tg` is or `val` or what "distance" means here, it's tough to say. Can you share some sample data and your desired results. I would agree that it *sounds* like a window function solution would be best here, but I don't understand what you are trying to do in the first place.

Comment: *Nearest neighbour* is usually based on latitude/longitude. What kind of information is stored in `val`?

Comment: I have updated the question, `val` is just decimal. Table `TG` consists of ids

Comment: Thanks for the update! What would be the "Nearest" neighbor here of `123123131`? I'm thrown off a bit by the "distance" function here: `sqrt(pow(<something>, 2))`, wouldn't that just return `<something>`? Couldn't we just sort all the cusotmers and then pick either the one "below" or the one "above" each customer based on which one is "Closer" when we substract the two (wrapping in `abs()`)?

Comment: Like: `min(val) OVER (ORDER BY val ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as previous_row` and `max(val) OVER (ORDER BY val ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) as next_row` and then just do a `CASE` on `Abs(val - previous_row)` compared to `Abs(val-next_row)` to see who is the winner .

Comment: @JNevill this is the great suggestion. However there is might be more than 1 'val' columns - this is kind of multidimensional task. I gave just one column to simplify the question

Comment: I think we will need to understand that multi-dimensionality/complexity to be able to help here. Is this is a lat/long thing where the geospatial functions may help?

Comment: There is no geospatial info

Comment: Well, you need to calculate all possible calculations before you can find the smallest. Maybe a looping approach helps: split the data into smaller chunks and find the nearest. Store that info in a table and use it in the next chunk in Where, thus you still need to compare all to all, but you avoid that huge intermediate result before ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: Or try to calculate your values into geospatial like `SELECT NEW ST_GEOMETRY('point ('||Trim(val1)|| ' ' || Trim(val2)||')')` (you might need to adjust the range of values to fit). Store it in a geospatial table, add a geospatial index and use ST_Distance to limit the amount of data (never tried that).